# Orchard - call external service in new thread

Tags: asynchronous, orchardcms

I have need to crate new thread for process external service call. In my module controller.

I need to insert id of created content item to thread method and use Orchard Services.

My situation:
¨

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateApplication(Apply postApply)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     var myItem = this._services.ContentManager.New("Zadosti");
     dynamic dynContentItem = myItem;
     dynContentItem.Zadosti.Jmeno.Value = postApply.Name;
     dynContentItem.Zadosti.Prijmeni.Value = postApply.SureName;
     this._services.ContentManager.Publish(myItem);

     // I need to get ID of created content item and call method in new thread
     CallMethodInNewThread(idOdContentItem);


  }
}

CallMethodInNewThread(int id){
   // External service async  CALL -> wait for response
   // Get content item with "id" from DB
   // Update and save content item
}
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: use the `await` keyword in your call

Comment: I do not wait for response... I want immidiately return view to user and run new thread in background (CallMethodInNewThread) and in this method i need to use IContentManager...